# Tabbing Through Lightswitch VS2013 HTML Table

Tags: html-table, user-input, lightswitch-2013

I have a simple VS2013 Lightswitch application that I need some help on.

There are two tables:

```
Materials
ID int
Product String

Containers
ID int
Name String
Inventory Double
Comments String
```

The relationship between Containers and Materials is a one(Materials)-to-infinite(Containers).

I created a custom Browse screen for Containers with a single Table element and some custom scripting for adding and saving the new containers, all of which is working fine.

My problem is that when a user clicks on the html table and starts to edit the items within, the tab key on the keyboard does not work as expected. Every time the keyboard tab is pressed, the first header cell of the HTML table is highlighted.  Progress through the rest of the columns within the table does not happen.  I did Google this and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c0055c8-367b-407d-a0f4-a33ae81dcc0e/html-client-edit-multiple-lines-of-data-in-a-table?forum=lightswitch) blog but it did not seem to effect anything.

Oddly enough, when I resize my IE screen to force the RWD, the tabbing works as expected.

Any thoughts on a remedy?

Answer (score 0):

refer to this thread I asked myself on the MSDN Forums which solved this problem:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c0055c8-367b-407d-a0f4-a33ae81dcc0e/html-client-edit-multiple-lines-of-data-in-a-table?forum=lightswitch

and incase the URL breaks:

if you go to the msls-2.5.1.js file, and go to line 28565, change the code here which shoul start with:

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
```

and end with

```
                break;
        }
    });
```

and change it to:

```
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case $.mobile.keyCode.ENTER:
                //if (header) {
                //    sortTableByColumn(table, header.cellIndex);
                //} else {
                //    msls_ui_CollectionControl.selectFocusedItem(table);
                //}
                break;

            //case $.mobile.keyCode.SPACE:
            //    if (header) {
            //        sortTableByColumn(table, header.cellIndex);
            //    } else {
            //        msls_ui_CollectionControl.toggleFocusedItem(table);
            //    }
            //    break;

            case $.mobile.keyCode.TAB:
                //Xpert360: tab in grid
                //if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "input")
                //    updateSelectedHeader(table, table._headerRowElement[0]);
                break;
        }
    });
```

this enables be to tab through a table view in Lightswitch HTML